# What's the Xcode "no such file or directory error"?

Tags: xcode

Xcode keeps prompting telling me I don't have a certain image in the project and it errors when I try to build. If I deleted the .png Xcode is complaining about from the project, why does Xcode error out when I try to build?

[Edited by Rhubarb (got too big for the comments)]

I'm getting the same thing with these details. The copy command looks like this

```
CpResource MyIcons/../13-bicycle.png /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-cxsohyxdecdbptgrrtaixbhhixrj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/13-bicycle.png
```

then there's a bunch of setenv and the command is translated to "builtin-copy" but none of that matters, the result is when I compile I get this error:

error: /Users/Me/Development/MyProject/MyIcons/../13-bicycle.png: No such file or directory

Now, I opened the Copy Bundle Resources tab as suggested by Robert Harvey, and my .png is there, with nothing appearing in read. And it is in the file system (Finder) and in the Project Navigator. So I deleted it from the resources using the - button and added it manually using the + button at the bottom left of the list in the Copy Bundle Resources tab. This put it at the root of the project in the Navigator, so I moved it into my group again - but no luck, same error. So I just deleted it altogether (from the Project Navigator, allowing it to be moved to Trash). That worked, but I ran into the same error with the very next icon (it only reports one or two at a time).

Looking at the error message, it appears to think that MyIcons is a folder. It's not, it's just a group. There is no such folder, I can see in the file system.

When I added via drag-drop, I left the "Copy items into ... group folder (if needed)" checked and the "Create groups for any added folders" button selected. But  note that I only dragged icons (en masse) into an existing group; I did not drag over any folders, nor where any groups or folders created. But somehow, the compiler thinks that these resources are in a folder in the file system that doesn't exist.

I right clicked the icon in the Copy Resources List and tried both Show in Finder and Reveal in Project Navigator: and both worked - the file is there and it knows where to get it - until it builds.

I haven't even found a workaround beyond deleting the icons yet - cleaning doesn't work. I think my group is corrupted.

Comment: Without the code or the error There is no way we can help you.

Comment: Twain wasn't asking you to give up! Edit your answer and insert the exact error and flagged code from Xcode.

Comment: I have the same problem after drag-dropping a bunch of images (glyphish icons) into my Project navigator and organizing them into Groups (with no backing folder). The error I get is:

Comment: ... I updated (and upvoted) the description instead

Comment: The Compile Sources build phase is not updated. Need to update that

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Answer (score 197, accepted):

look up here [XCode Build – CopyPNGFile Error and No Such File or Directory](https://web.archive.org/web/20121026181042/http://www.marbleblue.co.uk/xcode-build-copypngfile-error-file-directory/) .
I had same problem and this solution helps me.

> If you receive either of these annoying errors when building your
> xcode app, something has corrupted in your project bundle.
>
> 1. Open your project in Xcode
> 2. Click on your project
> 3. Click on your project under Targets
> 4. Hit the build phases tab
> 5. Open “Copy Bundle Resources” near the bottom
> 6. Look for any resources listed in red!

Comment: and when you find your resource listed in red, you can delete it by selecting it and hitting the delete button.

Comment: For me the problem was under Compile Sources. You're awesome, thanks!

Comment: For me, the file wasn't red. It's path was missing. Look for files with no path on the right of the filename.

Comment: Yes, Also for me the file wasn´t red in "Copy Bundle Resources" but when I selected this ".bundle" on the list and "Show in Finder" this did not appear on finder so I deleted. And add again the .bundle and worked!

Comment: @A.Trejo what do you mean "so I deleted and add the .bundle again" Where did you delete it from? Where did you add it again?

Comment: For me, I had the same file twice. when deleted one of them the problem was solved.

Comment: For me , the file was greyed out , I deleted the greyed out files , everything went OK.

Comment: In my case I clean project + Cleaned build folder and finally delete app from simulator/ Device . It worked like a charm!! Cheers ..

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be red. Sometimes it can be related to path remove and re-add if necessary.

Comment: Missing part: click the resources listed that showed up in your logs, and hit the minus sign to remove them. Thank you, @ED-209!! In my case, I was using react native, and I had to delete `ios`. It wasn't red here though, only in the logs.

Comment: In my case, in "copy bundle resources", there was a reference to a file that didn't exist. I deleted the reference.

Comment: My error was in Bundle React Native code and images script.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem but my solution was a bit different:

1. Open project in Xcode
2. Open project navigator
3. In the filter down below, search for your erroneous file name
4. I found the file under a group called "Recovered References" and it was marked in red
5. Delete the red files and everything should work perfectly

Comment: no such file or directory error gives me for libGTMSessionFetcher.a . It is under products and in products all lib files are red. So How can i solve this error.

Answer (score 7):

Okay here's the unsatisfactory workaround that fixed it for me.

(First, note that when I right-clicked my dodgy Group in the Project Navigator) it looked like any other group *except* that Open in External Editor was greyed - weird eh?)

1. I closed XCode and restarted it.

   => Now I see all of the icons under the offending group are red (in the Project Navigator)
2. Delete the entire group.
3. Create a new group (same name) and drag-drop the icons from the original source into the group

   => Error failed to copy (or some such - I can't remember but I have seen and fixed this before - and seen it elsewhere on SO)

   This error is due to leftover icons, so to fix this one now,
4. I deleted all other groups with icons and moved their icons to trash
5. open finder at the project location
6. delete every icon in the project (sort by kind, delete all the .png)
7. make a new group again, and drag all the icons in _again.
8. whew, now hit Builder

   => XCode crashes.

   Lovely.
9. Restart Xcode
10. fingers crossed: Build

=> it works. Brief celebration and back to work.

(See what I mean about unsatisfactory)

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you move the file named **-Prefix.pch,you can change the dictionary of the file ，do like this ： [the error about “no such file or directory”](http://www.cnblogs.com/ChenYilong/p/3588456.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check your project file paths. If there is a space in any of the folders, it causes this error. Simply remove spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Using XCode 10, I got this error after deleting some files I no longer needed in my project.
In my case, I went to XCode, clicked on the project name, then under **Resources**, the missing files were listed in red. All I did was to delete them.

In case you need the files, you will need to add them by going to File ->Add files to , then select the files. After selecting the file, make sure you have **Copy files if needed** checked.

Hope that helps someone.

HappyCoding

Answer (score 0):

try set target CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS=NO

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because the project folder was inside iCloud folder, not local folder and it was looking for \Documents\Documents.

Moved project folder to local location and it worked.

Answer (score -8):

XCode Build – CopyPNGFile Error and No Such File or Directory

If you receive either of these annoying errors when building your xcode app, something has corrupted in your project bundle.

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. Click on your project
3. Click on your project under Targets
4. Hit the build phases tab
5. Open “Copy Bundle Resources” near the bottom
6. Look for any resources listed in red!

Comment: Do not copy&paste the original answer!

Comment: Copy pasted answer