# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I am thinking of rebuilding the project from scratch which I would like to avoid, so I am asking for help.

When trying to build the project on release I get the following link error:

> Ld
>   /Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyStreamPlayer.app/MyStreamPlayer
>   normal armv7
>       cd /Users/MAS/iphoneApps/AlfsreamPlayer/MyStreamPlayer
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/MAS/iphoneApps/AlfsreamPlayer/MyStreamPlayer -L/Users/MAS/iphoneApps/AlfsreamPlayer/MyStreamPlayer/../build -F/Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Intermediates/MyStreamPlayer.build/Release-iphoneos/MyStreamPlayer.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyStreamPlayer.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Intermediates/MyStreamPlayer.build/Release-iphoneos/MyStreamPlayer.build/MyStreamPlayer-LinkMap-normal-armv7.txt -dead_strip -finalize -prefinalized-library libViewRightWebiOS.a -finalized-product /Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyStreamPlayer.app/MyStreamPlayer
>   -libVideoWebiOS -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework MediaPlayer -framework CFNetwork -libVideoWebiOS_debug -libVideoWebiOS -o /Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyStreamPlayer.app/MyStreamPlayer
>
> clang: error: no such file or directory:
>   '/Users/MAS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyStreamPlayer-auylvnjdlrkfpvaxnulcaadbfhwl/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyStreamPlayer.app/MyStreamPlayer'

No problem with debug mode. The project runs fine on another computer on xcode 4.5.1. I thought the xcode version could be the problem but when I tried it on another computer with xcode 4.5.1 I got the same problem.

The project uses a library `libVideoWebiOS`. I have it on the Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries. Any idea what produce could this issue? Here is the screenshot of build settings -> architectures.

[image: Architectures]

There are lot of suggestions to `Change "Build Active Architecure Only" to Yes` but unfortunately that didn't work for me.

Comment: What is the iOS deployment target?

Comment: @codingNinja iOS deployment target is set to 6.0

Comment: I guess you are missing some files, Check your `project` if you are having files that are not having `red` marks. Check this [No Such File Or Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167442/xcode-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

Comment: @arthan.v, yes I have one file named libVeri.a marked red in the products folder. Unfortunately going through the steps in the link did not solve it.

Comment: To integrate verimatrix cpm lib, you need to install Finializer before you build the release version. Please contact your vendor to get the integration tools and docs.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, it seems you are having `multiple targets` in your `project`. If you are using any `third party libraries` or `wrapper classes`, don't import the `project`. Add only the required `files and folders` you want. I don't know how to make the project in `release` mode which having `multiple targets`. But making your project with one `target` might solve your problem. 
Remove the `references` of your `third party project.xcodeproj` and add the `source files` what are all you needed in that `project`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes there are multiple targets in the project. It is needed for it to work. Any idea why it is working on one pc but not working in others pcs?

Comment: if it is working on one PC, check your added files in your `xcode` project, is in your project source or not. sometimes we might give reference to `files` in another location and forgot to copy it in our source code directory.

Answer (score 0):

Ron is correct, you must use the Finalizer before you can create a release build. Be sure you have Xcode closed for the finalizer to work.