# Accidentally deleted info.plist file under supporting folders: what to do?

Tags: xcode

I had done a lot of work in a project and when I tried to import a ton of images to put them under supporting folders something in the image files seemed to have caused xcode to start throwing errors and in a panic I accidentally deleted the info.plist file (that comes with a new project by default). This is not a file that I know anything about and I have just taken it for granted so far. Can anyone help me restore it, or do I have to start over? Thanks.

Comment: Get it from your repository. If you don't have a repository, take this as a reason to always work with a repository from now on.

Comment: I have my project on version control - I signed up for it when I created the project but I have never had to fall back on it before as my previous projects have been smaller. Do you know how I can access an earlier version? (I didn't add it to GitHub though).

Comment: Search for git in the Internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done this before. Check the Trash on your computer, it should be in there and re-add it to the project.

Comment: Thanks. I added them back in from trash but I'm still getting an error about 'no such file or directory for my project'. These errors only came about after I tried to import a set of images into my supporting folders that I had downloaded from a tutorial. What can I do to avoid this from happening in the future when it comes to importing images? I looked at this to resolve the issue but am experiencing same as a commentator called Rhubarb :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167442/whats-the-xcode-no-such-file-or-directory-error

Comment: What happens if you add those pictures under the main file and not the supporting folders?

Comment: I had deleted them from the navigator to trash but when I tried just now to import them together, Xcode said multiple errors occurred when trying to add them. Also, when I tried to add an individual one it said that an image with that name had already been added but I can't see where it is or how that could be the case as they are all in the trash.

Answer (score 1):

I also accidentally deleted my plist file, it wasn't present in trash neither in my repo (I had included it in .gitignore ,which I won't do in future). The thing which worked for me was one copy of this file was present in **platforms->ios->en.lproj** folder so I copied that file to **platforms->ios** folder and after that build was successful. Somehow this copy file was not showing in my vscode command pallete as well