# Realm Xcode Archive issue

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, realm

**Using:**

- Realm 2.0
- Swift 2.0
- Xcode 7

My app builds fine and simulates with no problem. But when I try to archive I get the following error:

```
bash: /Users/JohnDoe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Welli-gdlkrsxnhqwnqvgmklnmczogulzq/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Welli/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Welli.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory
```

I've updated my test targets build settings and I have the run script phase:

```
bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"
```

I've also tried deleting my DerivedData folder. I think there's some issue with framework search paths. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you put the script phase? It must be later than at least "Embed Frameworks" phase. Because the script acts on the embedded framework.

Comment: I agree it's probably a framework search path issue.  Find out what `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/` is and use Finder to see if it exists. If you don't know the shortcut open Finder and press cmd+shift+g to bring up the "Go to Folder" feature, there just copy and past the path and it'll try to take you there. If that fails then there's an issue.

Comment: You're using cocoapods?

Comment: You should try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167442/whats-the-xcode-no-such-file-or-directory-error?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this.