# SSZiparchive not getting removed from the project

Tags: ios, objective-c, objectivezip, ssziparchive

I have developed an iOS application using objective-c that uses a text file to be converted to zip. I initially tried using SSZipArchive and added the SSZipArchive to the project directory . Later , I changed to objective-zip and it works perfectly. And I have deleted the SSZipArchive Folder from the directory as well . But when I try to build the app , I get an error 'error: /Users/maneesh-3919/Documents/git1/mdmiosapp/support/SSZipArchive: No such file or directory' .. I tried searching "SSZipArchive" in the entire project but didn't find even one occurance. The Exact error that's being thrown is

```
CpResource support/SSZipArchive /Users/maneesh-3919/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mdmiosagent.app/SSZipArchive
cd /Users/maneesh-3919/Documents/git1/mdmiosapp
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/maneesh-3919/Documents/git1/mdmiosapp/support/SSZipArchive /Users/maneesh-3919/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/mdmiosagent.app

error: /Users/maneesh-3919/Documents/git1/mdmiosapp/support/SSZipArchive: No such file or directory
```

So Kindly assist me to remove the SSZipArchive completely . Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try searching for `SSZipArchive` in **Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources**. If its there, remove it.

Comment: voila !!! That did the trick. Please Post this as an answer. I'll accept.

Comment: Clean build folder & derived data folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the Xcode "no such file or directory error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167442/whats-the-xcode-no-such-file-or-directory-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps:

```
1. Click on your project in Xcode.
2. For your target, open the build phases tab.
3. Open "Copy Bundle Resources"
4. Look for any resources listed in red (SSZipArchive)
5. Remove.
```

Suggestion: You should prefer using Cocoapods for dependencies. It handles everything.